# How insects move opposite to gravity?

Tags: biology, adhesion

My question is very simple: How insects move opposite to gravity?  please dont tell me that they  have Sucks because my comment will be what about insects if move on smooth walls like glass.

Comment: Opposite to gravity? Is your question rather why insects don't fall of glass?

Answer (score 2):

From:
https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-flies-and-other-in/

> "The segments, or tarsi, at the end of insect legs possess clawlike structures that help the insect hold on to different types of surfaces. These tarsal claws are used to grip the tiny irregularities on rough surfaces. But in some cases, insects do make use of a kind of adhesion. If the surface is smooth, the insect can hold on using the adhesive action of hairs located on sticky pads (known as the arolia or pulvilli) on the tarsi.